# R absolute value of residuals with log transformation

Tags: r, regression, transformation

I have a linear model in R of the form

```
lm(log(num_encounters) ~ log(distance)*sampling_effort, data=df)
```

I want to interpret the residuals but get them back on the scale of num_encounters. I have seen `residuals.lm(x, type="working")` and `residuals.lm(x, type="response")` but I'm not sure about the values returned by them. Do I for instance still need to use exp() to get the residual values back on the num_encounters scale? Or are they already on that scale? I want to plot these absolute values back, both in a histogram and in a raster map afterwards.

EDIT:
Basically my confusion is that the following code results in 3 different histograms, while I was expecting the first 2 to be identical.

```
df$predicted <- exp(predict(x, newdata=df))
histogram(df$num_encounters-df$predicted)
histogram(exp(residuals(x, type="response")))
histogram(residuals(x, type="response"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to interpret the residuals but get them back on the scale of
>   num_encounters.

You can easily calculate them:

```
mod <- lm(log(num_encounters) ~ log(distance)*sampling_effort, data=df)
res <- df$num_encounters - exp(predict(mod))
```

Comment: Thanks. I was doing that too indeed, but then the docs seemed to suggest that `residuals.lm(x, type="response")` or `exp(residuals.ln(x, type='response'))` should yield the same results, and it didn't. So I started to doubt myself.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Roland. But this doc says that the response residual is indeed observed-predicted: https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/BinomTools/inst/ResidualsGLM.pdf
Thinking about it, the problem is just basic log arithmetics. I'll detail it in an additional answer.

Comment: @DolfAndringa To `lm` "observed" is `log(num_encounters)`.

Comment: Yeah, I just discovered that. See above. Thanks for bearing with me @Roland

Answer (score 1):

In addition what @Roland suggests, which indeed is correct and works, the problem with my confusion was just basic high-school logarithm algebra.

Indeed the absolute response residuals (on the scale of the original dependent variable) can be calculated as @Roland says with

```
mod <- lm(log(num_encounters) ~ log(distance)*sampling_effort, data=df)
res <- df$num_encounters - exp(predict(mod))
```

If you want to calculate them from the model residuals, you need to keep logarithm substraction rules into account.

```
log(a)-log(b)=log(a/b)
```

The residual is calculated from the original model. So in my case, the model predicts `log(num_encounters)`. So the residual is `log(observed)-log(predicted)`.

What I was trying to do was

```
exp(resid) = exp(log(obs)-log(pred)) = exp(log(obs/pred)) = obs/pred
```

which is clearly not the number I was looking for. To get the absolute response residual from the model response residual, this is what I needed.

```
obs-obs/exp(resid)
```

So in R code, this is what you could also do:

```
mod <- lm(log(num_encounters) ~ log(distance)*sampling_effort, data=df)
abs_resid <- df$num_encounters - df$num_encounters/exp(residuals(mod, type="response"))
```

This resulted in the same number as with the method described by @Roland which is much easier of course. But at least I got my brain lined up again.